# Trying to find the path to excel by searching the registry

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I'm trying to find the path to Excel using the registry, and have tried to adapt some code I've found on the internet. I'm using 64-bit Win7 and have confirmed the key is there using regedit.

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
HKEY hKey = 0;
char buf[255] = {0};
DWORD dwType = 0;
DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);
const char* subkey = "SOFTWARE\\Classes\\Excel.Application\\CLSID";

if( RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,subkey,&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    dwType = REG_SZ;
    if( RegQueryValueEx(hKey,"default",0, &dwType, (BYTE*)buf, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "key value is '" << buf << "'\n";
    }
    else
        cout << "can not query for key value\n";
    RegCloseKey(hKey);

}
else
    cout << "Can not open key\n";
cin.ignore();

return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?
Thanks
James

Comment: What error message occur when you execute the program.

Comment: Is your program 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: It's 64-bit, the problem wasn't that there was an error "RegOpenKey" didn't set the hKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the

```
RegQueryValueEx(hKey,"default",0, &dwType, (BYTE*)buf, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
```

with

```
RegQueryValueEx(hKey, NULL, 0, &dwType, (BYTE*)buf, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
```

If you want the "default" value, you should pass NULL or a empty string in the lpValueName field.

Also if your application is not 64-bit and you are running in a 64-bit OS, you should check the KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag on the RegOpenKeyEx function, to have access to the key you want.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all Windows API functions, when the fail, set a more detailed error code that you can get by calling `GetLastError()` for more details.  You should call that after a call to `RegOpenKey()` fails.

In your example, the `RegOpenKey()` is probably failing with an access denied error.  `RegOpenKey()` open a registry key with full read/write/delete access.  A standard user on Windows 7 doesn't have write or delete access on HKLM so `RegOpenKey()` will fail.

You should instead use [RegOpenKeyEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which will let you specify read-only access, as below.

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subkey, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey)
```

PS. When asking a question like the one above you should be more descriptive on how the code is failing.  In your example above you should include which line/function call is failing.  For example  "When I use this code, the call to RegOpenKey is failing.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response! I've tried implementing your changes but nothing alters. The program runs all the way through. I've included "std::cout << "Here " << GetLastError() << std::endl;" below RegOpenKeyEx, but it just displays "Here 0" which I take to mean no error has occurred. When I go through it with a debugger, after the RegOpenKeyEx line, the hkey variables has a value of "unused???" and when I press the plus symbol, it says "Error: Expression cannot be evaluated. I presume this means that hkey never got loaded?